# regex to remove substring and other characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string

```
var myName = 'names:(taga || tagb || tagc)'
```

and this regex to remove names: parentheses

```
  myName = myName.replace(/(names:)?\s*\(?([^)]*)(\)$)?/, '$2').trim();
```

and the output of the myName is : `taga||tagb||tagc`

and I have another

```
var myName2 = 'names:tag1names: || names:tag2 || names:tag3'
```

and i want to return : `tag1names:||tag2||tag3`, but it returns `tag1names:||names:tag2||names:tag3`

Can I have the regex to remove the first **names** of each string before ||  so it works for both cases

both input strings:

```
'names:(taga || tagb || tagc)' -> return taga||tagb||tagc
'names:tag1name: || names:tag2 || names:tag3' -> return tag1name:||tag2||tag3
```

Comment: why would you use a regex for this? Just test with an `indexOf` and string-replace? No need for an orbital cannon when a simple hammer will suffice. Regex make things harder to understand, and more prone to exploits. Just spend the few extra characters writing a bit of normal string `indexOf`/`split` code and you'll be much happier 3 days from now. Just as fast for short input, and infinitely easier to maintain

Comment: Have you tried the /g flag?

Answer (score 1):

Not completely sure of your complete use case, but maybe:

```
// try a sample
myName = "names:(taga || tagb || tagc)\nnames:tag1names: || names:tag2 || names:tag3";

// revised regex
myName = myName.replace(/(?:(?:\bnames:)?\s*\(([^)]*)\)|\bnames:)/g, '$1').trim();

// results in stripped output
myName == "taga || tagb || tagc\ntag1names: || tag2 || tag3"
```

I simplified some of your regex:

- You can use `(?:regex)` to ignore matching groups.
- You can use `|` to match different alternative expressions.
- When a matching group is in an non-matching alternative, the corresponding capture is blank.
- I used the `g` option for replacing all matches.
- You can use `\b` to ensure that you're matching words.

You can use tools like https://regex101.com/ to verify and experiment.  I added this specific regex: https://regex101.com/r/NEgbTu/1

Good luck!

Comment: thanks but for 'names:tag1names: || names:tag2 || names:tag3' -> return tag1names:||tag2||tag3.(tag1names: not tag1)

Comment: So, you don't want to breakup the tag1names: key?  Then you can add the additional \b to fix the name break.  I've edited the output above to show.